# File from the internet corrupted

Tags: java

I am downloading a file from the internet with this code.

```
void download(String source, String destination, int size) {
    // ten percent of the total download size
    File ofile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "", destination);
    System.out.printf("\nDownloading\n\t%s\nTo\n\t%s\n", source, destination);
    try {
        if (ofile.exists()) ofile.delete();
        if (!ofile.createNewFile()) {
            throw new IOException("Can't create " + ofile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        int inChar = 0;
        URL url = new URL(source);
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ofile);
        for (int i = 0; i < size && inChar != -1; i++) {
            inChar = input.read();
            fos.write(inChar);
        }

        input.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Downloaded " + ofile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then I run the updated program with another piece of code:

```
public Main() {

    needDownload();
    if (needDownload){

    download("http://www.endcraft.net/webstart/privateers.jar", "privateers.jar",6550225);
    try {
        String exec = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\privateers.jar");
        String[] command = {"javaw", "-jar", exec};  
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("Running " + exec);
        //System.exit(0);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

However, the downloaded jar appears corrupted.

```
"Error or invalid corrupt file /path/privateers.jar"
```

When I right-click the actual file and hit "run with java" (outside of the program), it also throws the same error.

However, when I download it directly from my FTP server and not from my application, it works fine and is not corrupted in any way.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check your URL `http://www.pirategame.net/webstart/privateers.jar` not downloading using browser

Comment: @Sarz Fair enough. Uncensored the link. I doubt that I care about the code being stolen as it only works if a server is present anyway.

Comment: Also in such cases look into the file, it could still be some text saying to the browser redirect to some download URL. So if you have no binary dump, try a .txt ending. Using a BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream will speed things up. Better: `Files.copy(input, oFile.toPath, StaqndardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Comment: Could happen if the `size` is not correct.

Comment: @JoopEggen The file seems fine.
http://gyazo.com/9206dc88fbc3759aa183a82a6dc07312
Also, what would a .txt ending do? And whats with this copy thing/where would I use it?

Comment: The correct URL works fine, when I simply call download from a main method: the .jar can be read without a hitch using jar -tf ...

Comment: What is your working environment? and is it desktop or web application?

Comment: (Saving as .txt would let you see whether the response might not be some text. Was already clear though, that the initial URL was wrong.) The `File.copy` part is a Java 7 utility that copies an InputStrem to a  file via `File.toPath()`. That may replace your entire copying loop. If you time both versions one should see a considerable speed improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
File file = new File("FileName.jar"); 
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

and append your `inChar` and write at once after for loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size && inChar != -1; i++) {
          // append
        }
 fos.write(inChar);
```

Comment: Testing 'inChar' in that way is futile. The damage has already been done, as in the Op's original code. It has to be tested immediately after the read.

Answer (score 1):

Add the last line:

```
  final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    System.out.println("Running " + exec);
  process.waitFor();
```

Highly recommended, if using the jar is the very next thing to do. Downloading may take a few secs.